# Efficient filter query for filtering on 80+ columns

Tags: sql, postgresql

There is a vehicle search system where users can select cars of their choice and a lot of filter options such as brand, model, color, features such as airbags, air conditioner etc. are given. There are dropdowns for choosing brand, model while the features are presented as checkboxes. There is also a field which shows the total no of cars falling in that criteria. Suppose, at first there are 100 cars. When the use selects brand as BMW the count gets updated to 47. Now, again if the user clicks on airbag(BMW + airbag), the total count gets updated.

The total no of features are 90. I am using PostgreSql and all the features are present in a single table. I want to build a dynamic query which should filter data based on user's preference. My approach is to put filter conditions for all 90 features and pass it the user's choice as parameters to the PostgreSql function.

```
select count(vehicle_id)
from vehicles
where brand in(...,...,...)
and flag_airbag in(..,..)
and flag_airconditioner in(..,..)
and ....
and .....
```

I believe there should be a better approach to achieve this. Any suggestion is appreciated.
Thankyou.

Comment: Your approach is quite reasonable.  You just need to be careful when options are not selected -- representing "all" with `in` is rather tricky.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That would work, but you would need indexes on all search criteria.

And you must make sure that the user enters at least one selective criterion, else (unless the table is small), your query will take long.

Having 90 indexes on a table is bordering on the insane; you won't be able to do any data modifications on the table with reasonable performance.

One approach would be to normalize the data somewhat: for example, a model always belongs to a specific brand, so you could have at least three tables `car`, `model` and `brand` and distribute the 90 attributes across these tables.

My advice is to always force the user to enter at least one or two conditions that are selective and have an index on those conditions. Then you can get away with way fewer indexes, and the use will be more satisfied, because nobody wants to wait long for a response and then get 10000 result rows.